# Add cumulative total sum over many columns in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.1, window-functions

My table is like this:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| id | type   | c1     | c2     | c3      |
+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| a  |      0 | 10     |     10 | 10      |
| a  |      0 | 0      |     10 |         |
| a  |      0 | 50     |     10 |         |
| c  |      0 |        |     10 | 20      |
| c  |      0 |        |     10 |         |
+----+--------+--------+--------+---------+
```

I need to the output like this:

```
+----+---------+--------+--------+---------+
| id | type    | c1     | c2     | c3      |
+----+---------+--------+--------+---------+
| a  |       0 | 10     |     10 | 10      |
| a  |       0 | 0      |     10 |         |
| a  |       0 | 50     |     10 |         |
| c  |       0 |        |     10 | 20      |
| c  |       0 |        |     10 |         |
+----+---------+--------+--------+---------+
|total |     0 | 60     |     50 |  30     |
+------------------------------------------+
|cumulative| 0 | 60     |   110  | 140     |
+------------------------------------------+
```

My query so far:

```
WITH res_1 AS 
  (SELECT id,c1,c3,c3 FROM cloud10k.dash_reportcard),
  res_2 AS 
  (SELECT 'TOTAL'::VARCHAR, SUM(c1),SUM(c2),SUM(c3) FROM cloud10k.dash_reportcard)       
SELECT * FROM res_1
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM res_2;
```

It produces a sum ***total*** per column.
How can I add the ***cumulative total sum***?

Note: the demo has 3 data columns, my actual table has more than 250.

Answer (score 3):

It would be very tedious and increasingly inefficient to list 250 columns over and over for the sum of columns - an O(n²) problem in disguise. Effectively, you want the equivalent of a window-function to calculate the running total over ***columns*** instead of ***rows***.

You can:

1. Transform the row to a set ("unpivot").
2. Run the window aggregate function `sum() OVER (...)`.
3. Transform the set back to a row ("pivot").

```sql
WITH total AS (
  SELECT 'total'::text AS id, 0 AS type
       , sum(c1) AS s1, sum(c2) AS s2, sum(c3) AS s3  -- more ...
  FROM   cloud10k.dash_reportcard
  )
TABLE cloud10k.dash_reportcard

UNION ALL  
TABLE total

UNION ALL
SELECT 'cumulative', 0, a[1], a[2], a[3]  -- more ...
FROM  (
   SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT sum(v.s) OVER (ORDER BY rn)
      FROM   total
           , LATERAL (VALUES (1, s1), (2, s2), (3, s3)) v(rn, s)  -- more ...
      )::int[] AS a
   ) sub;
```

See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102743/3684)

The last step could also be done with [`crosstab()` from the tablefunc module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860), but for this simple case it's simpler to just aggregate into an array and break out elements to a separate columns in the outer `SELECT`.

#### Alternative for Postgres 9.1

Same as above, but:

```sql
...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'cumulative'::text, 0, a[1], a[2], a[3]  -- more ...
FROM  (
   SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT sum(v.s) OVER (ORDER BY rn)
      FROM  (
         SELECT row_number() OVER (), s
         FROM   unnest((SELECT ARRAY[s1, s2, s3] FROM total)) s  -- more ...
         ) v(rn, s)
      )::int[] AS a
   ) sub;
```

Consider:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0d127eb4e17ce5e3d2f8728d48aff71b)* - demonstrating both
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1a87e/1)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Just add another `CTE` to get cumulative row:

```
WITH res_1 AS 
  (SELECT id,c1,c2,c3 
   FROM dash_reportcard),
  res_2 AS 
  (SELECT 'TOTAL'::VARCHAR, SUM(c1) AS sumC1,
          SUM(c2) AS sumC2, SUM(c3) AS sumC3 
   FROM dash_reportcard),
   res_3 AS
   (SELECT 'CUMULATIVE'::VARCHAR, sumC1,
           sumC2+sumC1, sumC1+sumC2+sumC3 
    FROM res_2)
SELECT * FROM res_1
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM res_2
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM res_3;
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/610c1/5)

Comment: Hi Giorgos, Thanking you very much.... Is their any another way? Y because more than 250 columns ....

Comment: @Madhulandoll If you have a table with more than 250 columns, then you should seriously consider redesigning your schema. A table with so many columns is almost guaranteed to violate 1NF.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH total AS (
  SELECT 'TOTAL'::VARCHAR, SUM(c1) AS sumc1, SUM(c2) AS sumc2, SUM(c3) AS sumc3
  FROM cloud10k.dash_reportcard
), cum_total AS (
  SELECT 'CUMULATIVE'::varchar, sumc1, sumc1+sumc2, sumc1+sumc2+sumc3
  FROM total
)
SELECT id, c1, c2, c3 FROM cloud10k.dash_reportcard
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM total
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cum_total;
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thanking you very much... Is their any another way? Y because columns or more than 250 ... Thanks for suggestion...